# Android async task download XML

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

Good day

I have application whitch downloads XML and show temperature on widget. It worked good when i press "update button" on widget and I call Load() method but another android phone need download XML in another thread. I trying use async task and in doInBackground() call Load(). I do not know where is a fault.

My Load()

```
public List<Contact> Load()
{
    final String URL = "http://192.168.1.110/index.xml";
    // XML node keys
    final String KEY_SONG = "data"; // parent node
    final String KEY_KEY = "id";
    final String KEY_NAME = "temperature";
    final String KEY_TEMPERATURE = "humidity";
    final String KEY_LATITUDE = "latitude";
    final String KEY_STATUS = "status";
    Databaze db = new Databaze(this);
    List<Contact> contacts;

    XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
    String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML from URL
    Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

    NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_SONG);
    // looping through all mista nodes <mista>
    for (int j = 0; j < nl.getLength(); j++)
    {
        Element e = (Element) nl.item(j);

        String name = parser.getValue(e, KEY_NAME);
        String temperature = parser.getValue(e, KEY_TEMPERATURE);
        String latitude = parser.getValue(e, KEY_LATITUDE);
        String status = parser.getValue(e, KEY_STATUS);
        String key = parser.getValue(e, KEY_KEY);
        int keyINT = Integer.valueOf(key);

            if(keyINT == 1){
            db.updateContact(new Contact(keyINT, name, temperature, latitude, status));

            }
            else{
    db.addContact(new Contact(keyINT, name, temperature, latitude, status));
            }
    }
    contacts = db.getAllContacts();

    return contacts;
}
```

And Async Task

```
    public class LoadDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<Contact>>
{
//  private ProgressDialog dialog;
  //  private Databaze db;
  //  private  List<Contact> contacts;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        //super.onPreExecute();

    }
            @Override
    protected List<Contact> doInBackground(Void... voids)
    {

        MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity();


        return mainActivity.Load();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<Contact> cont)
    {
    //  super.onPostExecute(contacts);
        contacts = cont;


        contacts = db.getAllContacts();      

    }
}
```

And getTemperature() this method show actual temperature on windget.

```
    private String getTemperature(Context context) {

       LoadDataTask task = new LoadDataTask(); 
        task.execute();

    String temperature = "-";
    db = new Databaze(context);
    contacts = db.getAllContacts();      

        for (Contact cn : contacts) {  
            temperature = cn.getName() + " °C";
            System.out.println(cn.getName()+ " °C++++");
        }           
    return temperature;
}
```

When I use this. Its not works

```
LoadDataTask task = new LoadDataTask(); 
        task.execute();
```

But when I call Load() in getTemperature so it works good.

Error code:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:274)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:125)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:308)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:121)
at android.app.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:680)
at com.example.hello.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:26)
at com.example.hello.MyWidgetIntentReceiver$LoadDataTask.doInBackground(MyWidgetIntentReceiver.java:161)
at com.example.hello.MyWidgetIntentReceiver$LoadDataTask.doInBackground(MyWidgetIntentReceiver.java:1)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
... 4 more
```

I use in MainActivity class in my project this code to load XML data. This works. But asynctask another class as above doesn´t works.

```
  public class LoadDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<Contact>>
{
    private ProgressDialog dialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        super.onPreExecute();
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        dialog.setMessage("Loading");
        dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected List<Contact> doInBackground(Void... voids)
    {
        return Load();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<Contact> cont)
    {
        super.onPostExecute(contacts);
        contacts = cont;
        dialog.dismiss();
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Polohy byly načteny", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: override doInBackground?

Answer (score 0):

The crash happens because you are trying to create a new Handler from a background thread.  Try creating it on the main thread, such as:

```
public class LoadDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<Contact>> {
    private MainActivity mMainActivity;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        mMainActivity = new MainActivity();
    }

    @Override
    protected List<Contact> doInBackground(Void... voids)
    {
        return mMainActivity.Load();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<Contact> cont)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I try it but still doesn´t works. Now: 
`An error occured while executing doInBackground()at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)`

And `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:203)`